# how can I highlight class methods, but not properties with python syntax in vim?

Tags: python, regex, vim, syntax

A follow-up to the question in [Issue 598](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/598).

In order to highlight class *methods*, while ignoring class *properties* with output (EXPECTED):

- self.foo
- self.**foo**( bar )

try the following:

```
\v%(self\.)@5<=\w+(\()\@=
```

However, this also highlights the first parenthesis (RESULT):

- self.**foo(** bar )

Is there a way to prevent the lookahead character from being included in the highlighted text? i.e. only highlight the text between self. and ()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex:

```
\v%(self\.)@5<=\w+(\()\@=
```

has a problem on the look ahead. Because the search is "very magic" (`\v`) you don't need `\@=` but instead `@=`. So this works:

```
\v%(self\.)@5<=\w+(\()@=
```